# Update integer and date column to null in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table where I want to delete a member from the club but I don't want to delete the member from the database, just leave the member without the club, reason why I'm trying to use patch instead of delete in this case. I tried to set the value to null but it is returning me this error  `Trying to get property 'NULL' of non-object`, is there a way I could do this?

I am not using migrations for the table, it's a table I already had created in postgreSQL, the column I'm trying to edit is nullable.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
        $trash = null;
        Member::where('doc_iden',$id)->update(array(
            'id_club'=> $trash,
        ));

        Membresia::where(['id_lec'=>$id,'id_club'=>$idclub,'fec_f'->$trash])->update(array(
            'fec_f'=>date('Y-m-d'),
        ));
```

I tried to do it with NULL instead of null and setting the value directly without using a variable but I have the same error and I don't know what to do here.

Update: The first bit works, the second doesn't

Comment: The code you have posted should work and there is no place the "Trying to get property 'NULL' of non-object" would be thrown in this bit? where does that error occour?

Comment: you should check where is the error from `Trying to get property 'NULL' of non-object` is not enough description and it's mostly from one of your blade trying to access the club's name or something like that `$member->club->name`... but since `$member->club` is null, it generates that error

Comment: @mrhn edited my question since just realized that the error isn't in that bit

Comment: @N69S I tried to return the values of $id and $idclub and it's returning the values properly, so it's not that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
'fec_f'->$trash]
```

should be

```
'fec_f'=>$trash]
```

Comment: oh my... lol thanks